# Laravel 5.4 Query Builder Implementing orderBy with groupBy

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I wanted to manipulate how data will be shown with cost layering methods such as **LIFO** and **FIFO**.

To get things started, here's my `query`:

```
$items = Inventory::whereActive('1')
        ->where('quantity', '>', 0)
        ->where(function($query) use($request) {
            $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->search.'%')
            ->orwhere('ref_code', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->search.'%');
        })->orderBy('created_at', 'dsc')
        ->groupBy('ref_code')
        ->get();
```

I wanted to use `groupBy` with `ref_code` so it will only show one data with the same `ref_code`, and I used `orderBy` with `created_at` and `dsc` for **descending** so that one data that will be shown will be the last one that was added. (Well, that's what I think that would happen).

But unfortunately, when I used `groupBy`, it only shows the first added data. How can I select the last data? I thought `orderBy` was gonna do the job but it didn't.

Comment: it is order by 'desc', not dsc

Comment: DESC and DSC will work the same way.

Comment: why you dont use latest() instead ?

Comment: Because there will be other data that has different `ref_code` to be grouped by, using latest() and first() will just return one row? Or am I wrong? Hehe.

Comment: I think interchanging your `orderBy()` and `groupBy()` may give the same current result

Comment: `Order by` is not an aggregate function and will not affect the order of each group. It affects the global order of results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an alternative way for this. If you have auto incrementing primary key as `id` then you can do it like,

```
$ids = Inventory::whereActive('1')
        ->where('quantity', '>', 0)
        ->where(function($query) use($request) {
            $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->search.'%')
            ->orwhere('ref_code', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->search.'%');
        })
        ->select('ref_code',\DB::raw('MAX(id) as ID'))
        ->groupBy('ref_code')
        ->pluck('ID');
```

Now, Get Items as

```
$items = Inventory::whereIn('id',$ids)->get();
```

Hence you will get your desired result.

Comment: I totally had this in mind but never knew I should used `pluck`! Haha, thanks for this. It worked perfectly. I was using `first` instead, and it didn't return any row.